# IVC 102 Integrator IC - Photodiode Simulation Issues

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, photodiode, texas-instruments, integrator

I am designing a circuit that integrates a signal output from an avalanch photodiode.

The component I am using is the [ICV102U](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ivc102.pdf). Before purchasing the IC, I want to run a few simulations using LTSpice. I am following a similar configuration to that in the product datasheet shown below:

[image: IVC 102 Recommended Configuration For Photodiode Measurements]

Since the diode I am working with is an APD, it requires a reverse bias voltage for the best response. Furthermore, the signal adheres to the following relation:

[image: Parameter-Dependent APD Signal Current]

In this relation the parameter defintions are as follows:

- I_0 -> diode saturation current
- e -> elementary charge
- V_rev -> reverse bias voltage
- a -> ideality factor (1 or 2, depends on semiconductor materials used in fabrication)
- k_B -> Boltzmann's constant
- T -> Junction temperature
- v_br -> breakdown voltage
- n_e -> external quantum efficiency
- P_s -> illumination power of incident light on APD
- h -> Planck's constant
- v -> frequency of light (reciprocal of wavelength)

Since the reverse bias voltage significantly influences the magnitude of the signal output by the APD, the configuration suggested by TI will be slightly adapted to allow the device to be biased. The schematic below shows the planned configuration when s1 (in the above image) is closed and s2 (also above) is open:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBHofX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By op-amp analysis, it can be found that both the inverting and non-inverting terminals are held at GND potential (0 V). This means that the voltage drop across the APD when the switch is closed is -Vbias (the reverse bias voltage), which sets the DC current output by the APD (assuming all other parameters in the above equation are constant).

Here is where my confusion starts:

TI states that in this state (s1 closed and s2 open) the output voltage is given by:

[image: Basic Integrator Model For DC Signal]

In this relation the parameter defintions are as follows:

- v_out -> voltage output at the end of integration period
- i_int -> signal being integrated (this would be APD current in my case)
- c_int -> integration capacitance (this is configurable)

This model also assumes that the initial voltage at the output is 0 (which is valid after reset). It also appears to assume that all of the current output by a photodiode will flow through the feedback path (containing the integration capacitors).

Can that even be true as you model the APD as a current source in parallel with a resistor and capacitor? More specifically, if you performed circuit analysis (using my circuit above) wouldn't current also flows through the resistor and capacitor (charge transfer)?

Furthermore, to reset the output voltage at the integrator output (bring it to 0 after the measurement/integration period) TI suggests opening s1 with s2 closed. This allows any charge developed across the integration capacitor to be discharged (current can flow to ground). During this period though, with current still flowing from the photodiode, TI claims that a voltage will be developed across the sensor based on the diode capacitance.

From the calculations in the datasheet, I assume that in this state (for their configuration, not mine) they are using the following equation:

[image: Voltage Developed Across Photodiode When Disconnected From Integrator]

In this relation the parameter defintions are as follows:

- v_d -> Voltage developed across photodiode
- i_int -> Same definition as above
- c_d -> Photodiode capacitance
- T_off -> The time that s1 is in the open position (photodiode disconnected from circuit)

I believe what TI is saying is that when s1 is open, the equivalent circuit is another integrator (presumably as shown below, but please correct me if I am wrong):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqVSNr.png)</sup>

Although, I do not fully understand the logic as the photodiode resistance still exists, so wouldn't it make sense if the resistance was accounted for in the above equation? Could someone explain how to model the behavior of the circuit in this state (for TI's configuration)?

Now, in my configuration, I expect that voltage drop across the diode would be influenced in the same state (s1 open and s2 closed), however, it would not follow the same relationship as above since I am biasing the APD (operating in photoconductive mode) rather than tying it to GND (operating in photovoltaic mode). That is if I assume the following configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSMaHv.png)</sup>

I am guessing that the voltage developed across the APD would follow the equation:

[image: Assumed Voltage Developed Across Biased Photodiode When Disconnected From Integrator]

The defintions for similar parameters are the same as above. The additional v_APD and v_bias, represent the voltage across the APD and the applied bias voltage respectively. I did not rigourously derive this equation, instead I leveraged the one for the previous configuration and proceeded by intuition.

If these are the correct equations, however, they are only valid under the assumption that the signal current is relatively constant over the time period where s1 is open. The voltage seen across the photodiode or APD during this time is assumed to change, and from the equation above for photodiode signal output, there is a voltage dependance. Thus, as the voltage changes across the APD, so will the current and the 2 relations above are invalid (if they are valid to become).

An explanation for how to derive the voltage across the APD (reverse bias configuration) in this state would be appreciated.

Maybe the 2 circuits above are an inaccurate representation of the overall circuit in this state (s1 open and s2 closed). Maybe it is necessary to account for the off resistances of the switches during the analysis?

You may be wondering what my goal is, and why I seek answers for these questions. For the application that this IC is to be used, the amount of illumination on the APD is not known. I want to be able to use the model for the integrator (or some other transfer function) to measure the time it takes for the output to ramp up to a fixed voltage, and have software that solves for the current being integrated.

It may be an issue though that during the reset period for the integrator, a different voltage (than bias voltage) is being applied across the APD. For different signal currents, the the developed voltage will likely be different/inconsistent. Furthermore, as soon as s1 is closed and s2 is opened (integrating period), the voltage developed at the inverting terminal of the integrator is transferred to the integration capacitor, and this becomes the initial voltage at the integrator output.The output voltage then expectedly follows the relation:

[image: Integrator Model Accounting For Transferred Charge At Start of Integration Period]

Most parameters in this relation have been previously defined. Except the new parameter, v_0 is the voltage at the inverting terminal of the integrator. While v_0 will be constant for a given signal current, it will not be constant over the range of currents being integrated. It will however be related to the voltage developed across the APD, v_APD during the reset period, which also won't be consistent across the range of currents being integrated.

What are everyone's thoughts on this? What knowledge/circuit theory do I require to determine accurate models for the voltage developed across the APD during the reset period of the integrator? I would appreciate any feedback on the validity of my explanation.

To best understand the operation of the IC according to TI specifications, I have linked the  datasheet here (the timing diagram for the switches is also useful): https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ivc102.pdf?ts=1637593022479&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FIVC102

Comment: The TI circuit (and arguments) are based on an unbiased photodiode. You appear to be trying to rationalize your circuit with the TI circuit but it ain't gonna happen is it?

Comment: @Andy aka are you saying that the TI circuit is not compatible with a biased photodiode configuration?

Comment: No, I'm saying your analysis is flawed.

Comment: I knew that was a possibility? Do you have any tips that will allow me to conduct an accurate analysis? I am stumped at this point

Comment: Your post is so long I started to gloss over things. You ought to drop the comparison and concentrate on what you real goal is. No more than 25% of the length of this post is needed I estimate.

Comment: Ok. I want to model the voltage seen at the inverting terminal after the period in which s1 is open

Comment: Well, it's still a virtual ground so it will be the same as prior to S1 opening.

Comment: The parallel resistor in the diode model is basically the same as your dark current expression (although there may also be a true leakage resistance that needs to be included). As others have stated the assumption is that the gain the opamp is very high so the input voltage is zero. In your last expression. What is v_o that you are questioning? It doesn't appear in the equation - that is vo = output voltage.

Comment: @KevinWhite the v_0 is the voltage that would appear at the cathode of the APD (in my configuration above) after s1 has been opened for some amount of time during reset. From my understanding of the datasheet, this voltage means a charge has accumulated on the APD capacitance, and when s1 is closed (ready to integrate) a path is created for this charge to flow, such that it accumulates on the integration capacitance. Thus, a non-zero voltage appears across the integration capacitance (and at the output) at the start of integration, causing measurement errors.